# Foreach loop not updating the values

Tags: php, foreach

I've for a few forms on the page. Before rendering them in my views, I create them dynamically in PHP with their buttons and elements. I want to adjust the tabindexes dynamically, so basically once I have all the forms ready at the end of the PHP script, I do the following:

```
public function fixTabindexes($forms) {

    $tabindex = 1;      

    $forms = count($forms) > 1 ? $forms : [$forms];

    foreach($forms as $form) {

        foreach($form['form'] as $element) {
            $element->setAttrib('tabindex', $tabindex++);
        }

        foreach($form['buttons'] as $button) {                                              
            $button['tabindex'] = $tabindex++;
        }

    }

    return $forms;

}
```

Elements get updated perfectly, but buttons don't. It feels as if the second foreach - `$form['buttons']` is not saving the `['tabindex']` key and it's value. However, if I do a `var_dump` inside the foreach loop, it shows up fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of yourse it doesent update as you dont update the array. Replace $button[tabindex] with another array where you save yor tabindex and return this array

Comment: Can you give us the var_dump from within the for loop and outside the for loop?

Comment: ... this is what working long hours does to one. Thanks!

Comment: foreach makes a copy of objects. To use the actual object (by reference) instead of a copy, use `foreach($form['form'] as &$element)`

Comment: can I not do it with array as well? just like in my case?

Comment: nevermind. I've done it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @SuchMuchCode Kindly answer your own question to share what you've found or delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments by others, I was missing `&` next to `$button` so it was making a copy of my array and not returning it. So adding `&`, kept the references and updated my array properly, BUT then another thing I was missing was the same - `&` with `$form` too.

```
public function fixTabindexes($forms) {

    $tabindex = 1;      

    $forms = count($forms) > 1 ? $forms : [$forms];

    foreach($forms as &$form) {

        foreach($form['form'] as $element) {
            $element->setAttrib('tabindex', $tabindex++);
        }

        foreach($form['buttons'] as &$button) {                                              
            $button['tabindex'] = $tabindex++;
        }

    }

    return $forms;

}
```